# Java 8 Optional How to define Error Message of NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-8, option-type

Before Java 8, we normally have to do like the following to fail fast for `Null` values.

```
Objects.requireNonNull(pointer, "Your Error Message");
```

According to Java 8 Documentation, `Optional.of` will throw `NullPointerException` if passed parameter is null.

```
// Optional.of - throws NullPointerException if passed parameter is null
Optional<Integer> b = Optional.of(value2);
```

Is there any way to define **error message** for `NullPointerException` in Java 8 `Optional`?

Comment: @4castle Yeah, got the point, thanks. But still a little un-satisfy why they put ".of" method in Optional class for NullPointerException fail fast. At least, they would provide optional parameter for error message like "Objects.requireNonNull".

Comment: When I said "fail last", I meant that you're supposed to belate throwing any errors until you try to retrieve the value from the `Optional` at the end. You have the option of using `Optional.ofNullable` also.

Comment: They didn't put that in because parameter checking is not really the job of `Optional` - it models 'optionality' (to specifically differentiate it from 'nullability'). If you want to enforce some contract, do that before you get to optional or optional will just fail when you ask it to make an instance with a null from its explicitly non-nullable method.

Comment: Yup.  You're not really _supposed_ to call `Optional.of` if you aren't completely sure.

Comment: @pvg really thanks for comment like that which contain both explanation and suggestion.

Answer (score 9):

You could always write `Optional.of(Objects.requireNonNull(pointer, "message"))`.

Answer (score 6):

For the `Optional` class, you're usually expected to not deal with throwing any errors until the value is extracted. You can use [`orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-) when you try to retrieve the value:

```
Optional.ofNullable(pointer)
        ...
        ...
        .orElseThrow(() -> new NullPointerException("message"));
```

The `Optional` class isn't meant to replace the existing methods for doing specific null-checking.